# How I can export a function without decoration?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, g++

I have a cross-platform(linux and windows) library.dll which implements a function:

`std::set<stds::string> function()`

Also I want to load the library by using `LoadLibrary()`, so I need export my function without decoration. I can't use `extern "C"` because the function returns C++ class.

Are there any methods to resolve the problem?

Comment: Yes, I know about .def file, but what about linux?

Comment: You're suggesting `LoadLibrary()` - a windows API function - is available under linux?    In any event, if you want a function "without decoration", sort out a return type that is compatible with C, make it `extern "C"`, and work out a way to cleanly convert the `std::set<std::string>` into a form that can be returned by your function.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `.DEF` file to specify the desired exported name.

[Module-Definition (.Def) Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/28d6s79h.aspx)

[Exporting from a DLL Using DEF Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d91k01sh.aspx)